# Python multiple instances of program writing and then reading the same file

Tags: python, file-io

I wrote a piece of python code that calls a external program to write an intermediate file and thereafter my code reads from it. I want to run multiple instances of my code simultaneously. Will there be any conflict if I code list this?

```
args=['/usr/bin/program','-o','intermediate_file']
process = subprocess.Popen(args,shell=False)
process.wait()
if process.returncode ==0:
    fh = open('intermediate_file', 'r')
    process(fh)
        ...
```

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Answer (score 3):

*Concurrent file access* is handled by the operating system. There are several scenarios, depending on the OS and or filesystem you use. Take a look at the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking)-article.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: [tempfile](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/tempfile.html)

You can make use of this lib to avoid conflicts - temp files have random names.

Comment: link broken. add an `'L'.lower()` to the end